# my basic php code producing unexpected results

Tags: plugin-development, posts, page-template

I am writing a code snippet to display attachments to a post but for each user, he should only be able to see his own attachments and not those of other users

```
    $current_user=wp_get_current_user();

    //display all post attachments. see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );
echo "<b><u>Uploads By me</u></b>"; 
echo "<ol>";
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {

        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            echo "<li>";
            the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
            echo " by author ".$attachment->post_author ;//debug info
            echo " and Current user is ".$current_user->ID ;//debug info
            if($current_user->ID==$attachment->ID) echo " Matched!! ";//debug info
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
echo "<ol>";
//end attacmnets
```

I placed the code in my custom page template and as you can see in picture below, the statement `if($current_user->ID==$attachment->ID) echo " Matched!! ";` failed and this is what i wanted to depend on to selectively show attachments.Please help out[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe you meant:**

```
if($current_user->ID == $attachment->post_author) echo " Matched!! ";
```

**PS**: *By unexpected results I think you are referring to the 'DISEASES OF THE PENIS' part... right?*

Comment: is 100% correct.  In this case, `$current_user->ID` is the ID of the user.  `$attachment->ID` is the ID of the attachment.  Try to keep variable/object scoping in mind when you do your comparisons.

Comment: @EAMann I still think it's the DOTP entry that caused unexpected results :)

Comment: I wasn't gonna go there :-)

Comment: Oh sorry. Am going to edit picture :-)